# Jogo da velha cliente servidor tcp

Tags: servidor, jogos

Tou a usar o `netbeans`, e o programa e o que esta neste link: [Jogo do Galo / Jogo da Velha com Protocolo de nível de Aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66560/jogo-do-galo-jogo-da-velha-com-protocolo-de-n%C3%ADvel-de-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Primeiro faço run do servidor diz : `server is running`
depois faço run do cliente: e aparece erro nas linhas 28 e 187 mas não diz que tipo de erro é, as linhas são estas :

```
try
    {
        server = new ServerSocket(5000,2);  // <- linha 28 erro !
    }
```

e o outro erro é este:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) 
{
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    TicTacToeServerProtocolo game = new TicTacToeServerProtocolo(); // <- erro 187 nesta linha !!
    game.execute();
}
```

Ambos os erros são do programa "TicTacToeClientProtocolo.java"

Corrijam-me se estiver a fazer algum procedimento incorrecto.
O jogo em questão é o "Jogo da Velha" tal e qual o que esta no link que forneci deste site tambem, é uma questão igual mas relativa ao notepadd++ mas o objectivo é o mesmo ou seja, por a funcionar o servidor e o cliente ao mesmo tempo (jogo da velha).

Sei que este codigo funciona (TicTacToe) porque vi a funcionar num amigo meu que me forneceu este codigo. Ele tambem usou o netbeans.

Na saida "Output" aparece exatamente esta mensagem:

```
run:

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at TicTacToeServerProtocolo.<init>(TicTacToeServerProtocolo.java:28)
    at TicTacToeServerProtocolo.main(TicTacToeServerProtocolo.java:187)

Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro de **Address already in use: JVM_Bind** significa que já tem alguma aplicação rodando nessa porta, você precisa eliminar essa aplicação ou mudar sua porta de 5000 para outro valor mais alto.

Quanto mais alto, menor a chance de estar sendo utilizada.

Para procurar quem está utilizando essa porta pode fazer asssim:

**Windows**

1. Executar `resmon.exe`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Aba Redes > Portas de Escuta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Linux**

> netstat -tulpn

Comment: Já alterei as portas para valores 6000,9000 etc, e alterei o porto no cliente e no servidor, só alterei duas linhas, só o porto, meti igual porto no cliente e no servidor. Aparece o mesmo erro. Mas no netbeans fazendo run do cliente, não dá para alterar a porta, posso alterar no codigo o port, mas quando quero abrir outro cliente, fazendo run ele vai para o mesmo port que indiquei, eu acho que os dois clientes devem estar em portos diferentes, mas corrigenme se estiver errado.

Comment: A linha que está dando erro é no seu `ServerSocket` justamente pelo motivo que expliquei acima, você precisa rodar ele em outra porta e dessa forma o cliente conectar nessa mesma outra porta.

Comment: @insyspower Você não está a executar new TicTacToeServerProtocolo() mais de uma vez quando troca de porta?

Comment: Já conegui! O meu erro era tava a fazer run TicTacToeServerProtocolo.java, no entando assim dá aquele erro, tenho de fazer a pasta poda TicTacToeProtocolo que contem todos os ficheiros.